# Android - Cant see the incoming calls when LayoutParams.TypeSystemError is displayed

Tags: java, android, service, lockscreen, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm developing lock screen app. Here Lock screen is displayed on the top of the screen using this command "WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;"

But my problem is I can't See the Incoming call Window when the custom lock screen is displayed. Incoming call window is not overrided over my custom lock screen.

1) Is there any permission required for displaying the incoming call window.?

2) We have to add any other codes for answering the incoming class

This is my Lockscreen receiver class

```
public class LockScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

In the normal lock screen apps -> They can attend the incoming calls and after attending that call, lock screen is displayed. How ????

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Add receiver in the manifest and ask for permission

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".IncomingCall">   
           <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
           </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>`
2. Create class `IncomingCall`

   ```
   public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       try {
               TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                       .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

               MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

               // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
               telephonyManager.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   ```
3. Implement `PhoneStateListener` in `LockScreen` and call `onCallStateChanged`

   ```
   private class LockScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements PhoneStateListener{

       public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

           //Disable lockscreen when calls come

       }
   ```